# How to make a Textview display a number?

Tags: android

I'm new to Android development. I tried to make a Textview display a text or number and it crashes. Please Help.

This is the button in activity_main.xml:

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:text="@string/Change" 
        android:onClick="change"/>
```

and this is the Main Activity:

```
public void change(){
        TextView tv = new TextView(this);
        tv.setText("" + 4);
    }
```

the application crashes when i start it. I wanted to create a basic calculator with two text boxes and a button which when pressed adds the value in two text boxes and display it. can anybody tell me where I am going wrong with the code?

Comment: Take a look on logcat and whatever error you are facing share it here.

Comment: Show your activity code or Easiest way is, you have to declare text view in xml file and then initalize it in your activity oncreate method and then set text in it as you set in your code.

Comment: check my edit about the error: **TextView cannot be resolved to a type**

Answer (score 4):

```
    public void change()
    {
       TextView tv = new TextView(this);
       tv.setText("4");
    }
```

and if it is any kind of integer variable, then

```
    public void change()
    {
       TextView tv = new TextView(this);
       tv.setText("" + integer_variable);
    }
```

and also, check if the textView is plumbed with the code

TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.Id.textView1);

should have worked fine, I hope.. :)

If it crashes again, then the information in the question may be incomplete.

Happy Coding..!

Answer (score 2):

```
public void change(){
        TextView tv =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        tv.setText(Integer.toString(4));
    }
```

Comment: I changed it but yet the application crashes..?? :(

Comment: please post your logcat entry.

Comment: I'm getting TextView cannot be resolved to a type... import TextView (android.widgets) was a quick fix... does this have to do with anything???

Comment: use Ctrl+shift+O to import missing files. Note: It's not zero but alphabet O.

Answer (score 1):

**layout_contact.xml:**

```
 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:text="@string/number1" />
```

**strings.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
 <string name="number1">0091010</string>
</resources>
```

**ContactFragment.java:**

```
String num = "0091010";
textView8.setText(someContactNum);
```

**Output:**

0091010

Answer (score 0):

You have to give id of the text view properly in the xml like

```
    <TextView 
   ....
   android:id="@+id/tvID"/>
```

Check it you gave it properly or not..
 Otherwise here share your textview  code from your xml file..

And also checkit, you import the Textview in your code or not like this:

```
import android.widget.TextView;
```

Answer (score 0):

*Here is the answer for how to display the dynamic numbers in a single text view*

```
    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
                for (int j = fromNumber; j <= toNumber; j++) {
                    for (int i = 2; i <= j / 2; i++) {
                        if (j % i == 0) {
                            isPrimeNumber = false;
                            break;
                        } else {
                            isPrimeNumber = true;
                        }
                    }
                    if (isPrimeNumber) {

                        stringBuilder.append(j);
                        stringBuilder.append(",");
                    } else {
                    }
                }
                tvResult.setText(stringBuilder.toString());
```